# Solution for Calling Clients from Server Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services

I have a Windwos Application (Let's name it App) and a WebService Project (name it WS) and a SqlServer Database (DB), and the technologies are all from Microsoft and .net.

The roles are that whenever App needs to do an action, it calls WS and WS does the magic work with DB and then returns the result to App.

So far, so good, but I need something more than that. I need a third Application, let's call it a Robot, this Robot monster should have the ability to find all alive clients (App instances) and not kill, but call them on some specific times, then the App(s) will decide do an action on being called.

My information lacks here, and that is why I want you guys to help me find the best solution for this Server-Calls-Client-And-Client-Does-Something thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have very short handed and pragmatic solution ideas:

1. Each client application invokes a method for instance `YesIamAlive()` of the webservice each x seconds/minutes. If the server gets this request it will be saved so you are be able so see which clients are alive. Each client which not sending an alive request for the last x seconds / minutes is not any longer alive. Another method which is also called on a routinely basis and it forces the client to do an action.
2. You could use SignalR for a websocket communication between your server and client. This example shows a chat server, which is not simular to your request but it shows the idea behind it: 
   http://braindrivendevelopment.com/2013/01/28/signalr-with-windows-azure-cloud-services/

I am quite sure that there are even more elegant solutions for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[SignalR](http://signalr.net/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)) is an excellent framework for "pushing" to clients in near real-time. It works with both web and WinForms clients.